# Powershells script to Re-name Local Guest & Administrator Account?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, user-accounts

Does anyone have a PowerShell script that will rename a local user account (Guest & Administrator)?
I am looking for something along the lines of what i have below or something close enough.

```
function Set-NewUserName{
    param($OldUserName, $NewUserName)
    #Implement Black Magic to change username.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use WMI to do this.

```
$user = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='$oldName'"
$result = $user.Rename($newName)

if ($result.ReturnValue -eq 0) {
return $user
# you may just print a message here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift and surprisingly simplistic result I was afraid i would have to use ADSI to perform this task.

Comment: +1. :) Does it cause problems with installed softwares, registry settings and so on?

Comment: I would say no in the majority of the cases, because the username is tied to a SID and that is what the system ultimately uses to grant or deny permissions. There are certainly edge cases where programmers don’t follow accepted practices and implement security incorrectly and changing the name can screw things up.